# UITextField Stops Responding To Touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a storyboard with a UIView with two UITextFields within it. When I navigate back to the controller the UITextFields no longer respond to touch. I am navigating to the controller like this

```
UIViewController* controller = [self rootNavigationController].storyboard] 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mycontroller"];
```

for some reason once I do this, they stop responding.

As far as the controller is concerned, it only has a few IBOutlets

myController.h

```
@interface myController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *field1;
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *field2;

@end
```

myController.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];
    [self.field1 becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.field2.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor colorWithRed:4.0/255.0
                                                           green:108.0/255.0
                                                            blue:187.0/255.0
                                                           alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    self.field2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    self.field1.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor colorWithRed:4.0/255.0
                                                           green:108.0/255.0
                                                            blue:187.0/255.0
                                                           alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    self.field1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
}
```

I have the IBOutlets hooked up on the story board.

I've tried cliptobounds on the mainView. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Your first two lines of code are supposed to navigate from what controller to what controller? Have you tried using segues and navigation controllers? In general there is no need for instantiating viewControllers by hand

Comment: I have a series of controllers that can be navigated to via the navigation controller. This controller is used as a sign in view. So you can log out at anytime and get back to this one. I am pushing the views to the navigation `[self pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`

Comment: The code you show doesn't navigate back to a controller, it's creating a new instance. You should be calling popViewControllerAnimated:  or popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing with the following code:

```
UIViewController* controller = [self rootNavigationController].storyboard] 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mycontroller"];
```

You're creating a new instance of `mycontroller`. That's why, as you said: " once I do this, they stop responding."

Therefore, the solution to your problem would be, not to create a new instance of the previous `viewController`, but to just navigate back. Here is what I mean:

Remove this:

```
UIViewController* controller = [self rootNavigationController].storyboard] 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mycontroller"];
```

And in place of that, insert the following:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this helps!! :)